# Code not outputting a value in hackerrank

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a hackerrank problem where I calculate the total meal cost given a base cost, tip, and a tax rate. Even when I return the correct answer in visual code, nothing is outputting when I submit it using hackerrank. 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-operators/problem

```
def solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent):
    tip = tip_percent*meal_cost
    tax = tax_percent * meal_cost
    total_cost = meal_cost+tip+tax
    return round(total_cost)
```

Comment: I think hackerrank wants you to print out the total cost instead of returning it.

Comment: Thanks man. I guess I didn't read the instructions carefully. I generally use codewars and print is disregarded.

Answer (score 2):

From the link you posted:

> **Output Format**
>
> Print the total meal cost ...

So, you have to use the `print` function, not the `return` statement.